# Compare generic two objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a simple comparison on two objects, simply to track changes on saving to the database, I have the below code which works perfectly on simple objects.

```
        public static List<Variance> Compare<T>(this T original, T current)
    {
        var variances = new List<Variance>();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var v = new Variance
            {
                PropertyName = property.Name,
                Original = property.GetValue(original),
                Current = property.GetValue(current)
            };

            if (v.Original == null && v.Current == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if ((v.Original == null && v.Current != null) || (v.Original != null && v.Current == null))
            {
                variances.Add(v);
                continue;
            }
            if (!v.Original.Equals(v.Current))
            {
                variances.Add(v);
            }
        }
        return variances;
    }
```

but if `T` is a list the equals need to be changed to a `SequenceEqual` and I can't think of a way to convert `T` to the correct list type to do the `SequenceEqual` check.

Comment: What is the list type of `T` that you are trying to convert to?

Comment: It could be anything, its a generic method to compair two objects complex or not

Comment: So what exactly is the problem you are having, since it could be anything? Please provide a solid example of what is **not** working. Your code sample is working code? What's the question? What line of code throws an error? What is the error?

Comment: The check may not be simply switching to `SequenceEquals`, as that would only compare each element of the lists using their plain `Equals` method, instead of property by property comparison like you're doing. If T is an `IEnumerable` you can use a foreach in it and recursively call the comparison on each pair of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's not impossible to use `SequenceEqual` here, it'd involve either `dynamic` like in Jasper Kent's answer, or quite a lot of reflection code, I'll outline what you'll need to do if you were using reflection:

- check if both the objects are `IEnumerable<T>`.
- get the `Type` of both objects, and then get the type parameter `T` as a `Type` as well
- get the method `SequenceEquals` from `Enumerable` as a `MethodInfo`. This involves using LINQ to find the overload with two parameters.
- call `MakeGenericMethod` with `T`.
- `Invoke` the `MethodInfo`

I wouldn't want to read, or write that code... Using `dynamic` is fine I guess, though some people have different opinions...

So here's a third way: I suggest you write your own `SequenceEqual` method that takes `IEnumerable`s (the non-generic version):

```
private static bool SequenceEqual(IEnumerable first, IEnumerable second) {
    IEnumerator e1 = first.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator e2 = second.GetEnumerator();
    try {
        // adapted from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,63644a881e976b52,references
        while (e1.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!(e2.MoveNext() && e1.Current.Equals(e2.Current))) return false;
        }
        if (e2.MoveNext()) return false;
        return true;
    } finally {
        if (e1 is IDisposable d1) {
            d1.Dispose();   
        }
        if (e2 is IDisposable d2) {
            d2.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just check whether the objects are `IEnumerable`:

```
if (v.Original is Enumerable e1 && 
    v.Current is Enumerable e2 &&
    !SequenceEqual(e1, e2))
{
    variances.Add(v);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution you want is to use dynamic overloading.

I've cut this solution down from yours to get to the nub of it. The call to `SwitchEquals()` is the equivalent of your `v.Original.Equals(v.Current)`.

```
static bool SwitchEquals<T>(IEnumerable<T> listA, IEnumerable<T> listB)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing Sequential Equals");

    return true; // Do your sequential equal here
}

static bool SwitchEquals(object objA, object objB)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing equals");

    return objA.Equals(objB); // This is your original equals
}

static void Compare<T>(T original, T current)
{
    // Using dynamic means the decision between the tow SwitchEquals methods is made
    // At runtime, when the system knows if we have a collection
    if (SwitchEquals ((dynamic)original,(dynamic) current))
        Console.WriteLine("Match");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No match");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Compare(4,5);

    Compare (new int[] { 4, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 4 });
}
```